# Windows Phone capabilities check

Tags: c#, mobile, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is there a website or application that would allow me to see what capabilities does my Windows Phone 8.1 device support? I'd need to do checklist of the capabilities for example of this device ( http://www.dell.com/us/p/dell-venue-8-pro/pd ) ie. ID_CAP_NETWORKING, ID_CAP_MAP but I cannot find that kind of list from here for this device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to know what capabilities your device has then you need to take a look at the specifications for your device. the capabilities you refer to here  (eg. `ID_CAP_NETWORKING, ID_CAP_MAP` ) are capabilities that is allowed to use by the app when you check these on in the `WMAppManifest.xml` file.

But there are some Capabilities on the list in WMAppManifest.xml that requires specific hardware specs.

`ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA` = Provides access to the Rear or Front camera (provided you have front cam)

`ID_CAP_PROXIMITY` = Provides access to NFC capabilities.

`ID_CAP_REMOVABLE_STORAGE` = Provides access to removable SD cards

`ID_CAP_SENSORS` = Provide access to all device sensors ( In some phones some sensors like Gyro, Compass is not available)

`ID_CAP_WALLET_SECUREELEMENT` = Provides access to a Wallet secure element for secure NFC transactions ( only if your device has NFC)

The rest of the Capabilities are pretty much available in all devices. Apart from some like **Gyro**, **Compass**, **Front** **Camera**, **NFC** which can not be found in some devices.

So if you want to know what capabilities that you can use in your phone (if you are a developer) then you need to find the specs for your phone and take a look at what capabilities you have and to use them check appropriate capabilities in the `WMAppManifest.xml`

to learn more about Windows Phone capabilities follow [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206936(v=vs.105).aspx) link

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't exactly the solution I was looking for which would provide web page or similar that can be accessed via the device to view the list what ID_CAP-properties are available for the current device in but sufficient thanks.